# How can I add header files to gcc in mac os x 10.6

Tags: iphone, gcc, macos, header, include-path

I want to build a static library that requires openssl for iPhone. It can't find include files from openssl. How should I tell the compiler where to look for those header files? Thanks.

EDIT: I'm trying to build librtmp for iPhone, for arm not for simulator. Just to test something. Im not building it from xcode. I think i have found [INCLUDE_PATH](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html) , I'm going to try if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included both INCLUDE_PATH and C_INCLUDE_PATH and it seems they work. There is also the compiler option -Idir and -Ldir for includes and libraries. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options

Answer (score 1):

In your Project Properties, look for "Header Search Paths" under "Search Paths"